# How to concisely set every element in a cv::Mat to some scalar, like cvSet

Tags: c++, opencv

In the old C api, you could use `cvSet(matrix, cvScalar(500.0));` to set all values of `matrix` to 500.  What is the equivalent way to do this in the C++ api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
matrix = 500;
```

where `matrix` is a `cv::Mat` object